# Ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is the set of polynomials $a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_nx^n$, where $2^{k+1}$ divides $a_k$, 
an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$? How should I think about this?

Comment: What happens under multiplication with $x$?

Comment: @martini: nice hint, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you se what happens when you multiply an element of that set by a polynomial; by $x$ for example?

Another approach, your set contains the constant $2$; if it were an ideal, it should contain all polynomials divisible by $2$. Does it?

Comment: I get it, thanks!